# Left aligning a group of lines

Tags: align

I want to make the following.
[image]
But I am able to make the following.
[image]
MWE

```
\begin{align*}
 &\left. 
 \begin{tabular}{l}
$u$ \text{(up)} \\
$d$ \text{(down}) 
 \end{tabular}
 \right\}\rightarrow \text{doublet}\\
 &c \text{ (charm)} \rightarrow \text{singlet} \\
 &s \text{ (strange)} \rightarrow \text{singlet} \\
 &t \text{ (top)} \rightarrow \text{singlet} \\
 &b \text{ (bottom)} \rightarrow \text{singlet}
 \end{align*}
```

I will be glad if someone can help me.

Comment: Please, don't add code as an image.

Comment: @egreg inserted the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of `align`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
$\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \textit{u} (up) \\
  \addlinespace
  \textit{d} (down)
\end{tabular} \right\}$ \textrightarrow{} doublet \\
\addlinespace
\textit{c} (charm) \textrightarrow{} singlet \\
\addlinespace
\textit{s} (strange) \textrightarrow{} singlet \\
\addlinespace
\textit{t} (top) \textrightarrow{} singlet \\
\addlinespace
\textit{b} (bottom) \textrightarrow{} singlet
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A couple of comments: we need to cheat a bit for the first two lines, which are typeset as a nested `tabular`. We need `\left.` and so we also need to remove the space of size `\nulldelimiterspace` that TeX would insert in place of the missing delimiter. I inserted `\addlinespace` in order to space out a bit the lines.

I'd prefer an alternative layout, where spreading lines is not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
\toprule
Symbol & Name & Kind \\
\midrule
\textit{u} & up & doublet with \textit{d} \\
\textit{d} & down & doublet with \textit{u} \\
\textit{c} & charm & singlet \\
\textit{s} & strange & singlet \\
\textit{t} & top & singlet \\
\textit{b} & bottom & singlet \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @egreg 's solution is perfect, as usual. But to be more explicit,  in the first code the two impotrtant things are (1)  `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace` deeded to remove  the unwanted spacing added by `\left.`, AND (2) the `@{}` in  `tabular` preamble to remove the extra column separator space.

Comment: @Jhor You're right, I added some comments about the first table.